# R Shiny -- "Not Found" error shown after modify config file

Tags: r, shiny

I installed shiny server and deployed a few apps and it runs well, I simply added apps by adding sub locations in the config file while keeping the base  location unchanged, like:

[image]

Then I can normally access `http://*URL*/` and `http://*URL*/Hello_Duck` and `http://*URL*/Ramjet`.

Then I want to set the Duck_Gua app as the base location so simply modify the config file to:

[image]

After reloading, the base URL `http://*url*/` still works fine showing the Duck_Gua app but when accessing the sub apps of `http://*url*/Hello_Duck` and `http://*url*/shiney-server`, a "Not Found" error was given.

Why is there this error? Does the base URL have to be referred to the default setting of "/srv/shiny-server"?

Comment: I think there is a typo at  location /shiney-server. Also you need to put / after locatio /Hello_Duck

Comment: Thanks Suliman, I changed to http://url/shiney-server and still does not work, neither after adding / after location, as there is not / in the default config file.